# Log folder is not created when we do 'mvn test' in linux for selenium

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, linux-mint

I have used the log4j2.xml for creating the log files, but in Linux it didn't work, it is not creating any folder or file but, if i execute the same code on windows machine then it is working as expected.

**On Linux:**
I have used Openjdk 11 and Linux v20. The machine is located in EC2 instance. And the project is cucumber selenium project, selenium-3 is used and cucumber 4 is used.

**Log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:logFilename}">
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:logFilename}"
                        fileName="target/logs/${ctx:logFilename}.log" filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
                        append="true">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n" />
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Mvn dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

**Snippet of mylogger class**:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static synchronized void startTestCase(String sTestCaseName) {
        sTestCaseName = sTestCaseName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "_").replaceAll("_+", "_");
        startLog(System.getProperty("user.dir"), sTestCaseName);
        info("\n\n************** Execution Started : " + sTestCaseName + "**************\n");
    }
```

**calling for class:**

```
MyLogger.info("NavigateToClearanceSpans Method Executed...!!");
```

Not sure why it is not creating log folder and file, i have tried with 'sudo mvn test' execution also but it is not working. also i have changed the location of folder creation but no luck.

Not sure how to fix, please let me know that.

Thanks.

Comment: try adding <scope>test<scope>

Comment: it didn't work,